htmx:swapError triggered by fast navigation clicks
I'm working with htmx for dynamic content loading in my project, and I've encountered an issue where the htmx:swapError is triggered when users click too quickly on the navigation links.
Here's the relevant portion of my HTML:
<div hx-boost="true" hx-target="main" hx-swap="outerHTML show:unset" class="w-full mx-auto">
    <div
        class="relative flex flex-col w-full p-5 mx-auto md:items-center md:justify-between md:flex-row max-w-7xl lg:px-16 md:px-12 px-8 xl:px-24"
    >
        <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-between lg:justify-start">
            <a href="#" class="text-xl text-gray-900 font-semibold tracking-tighter inline-flex gap-2 items-center">
                DXTA
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav class="flex-col flex-grow py-12 lg:py-0 md:flex md:justify-end md:flex-row hidden">
            <ul class="space-y-2 list-none lg:space-y-0 lg:items-center lg:inline-flex">
                <li>
                    <a
                        href="#"
                        class="px-2 lg:px-6 py-4 md:px-3 text-sm font-semibold text-slate-600 hover:text-purple-900"
                    >
                        Dashboard
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a
                        href="#"
                        class="px-2 lg:px-6 py-4 md:px-3 text-sm font-semibold text-slate-600 hover:text-purple-900"
                    >
                        Some stuff
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a
                        href="#"
                        class="px-2 lg:px-6 py-4 md:px-3 text-sm font-semibold text-slate-600 hover:text-purple-900"
                    >
                        Some other stuff
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

I suspect that the error is caused by rapid navigation clicks overwhelming the htmx requests. Is there a way to mitigate or handle this issue within htmx? Or are there best practices for managing rapid user interactions with htmx-based navigation?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Look into hx-sync in htmx docs. If that doesn't work you can try adding queue:all to the trigger attribute eg hx-trigger="click queue:all".
